# Unpermitted parameters in the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Models

prd_item.rb

**has_many :prd_allisland_flat_deliveries, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :prd_item**

prd_allisland_flat_delivery.rb

**belongs_to :prd_item**

in Main form

```
 <%=  p.fields_for :prd_allisland_flat_deliveries  do |i| %>

   <%= render(:partial => 'prd_allisland_flat_delivery_field', :locals => {:f => i})%>
 <% end %>
```

in the prd_allisland_flat_delivery_field  form partial

```
   <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 25px">
          <div class="col-md-2"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <%= f.label :delivery_period %>
          </div>



            <div class="col-md-4">


     <%= f.text_field(:delivery_period, {placeholder: '0', class: 'form-control input_border input_field_text_align_right'})%>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2"></div>
   </div>

        <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 25px">
          <div class="col-md-2"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <%= f.label :delivery_rate %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <%= f.text_field(:delivery_rate, {placeholder: 'Rs. 0.00', class: 'form-control input_border input_field_text_align_right'})%>
          </div>

        </div>
```

in prd_item controller

**def new

```
@item = PrdItem.new

@item.prd_allisland_flat_deliveries.build
```

end**

after writing this the create method

**

```
if @item.save

  if @item.delivery_type == 1

     @all_island_flat = @item.prd_allisland_flat_deliveries.build(item_params[:prd_allisland_flat_deliveries_attributes])
    @all_island_flat.save
  end
```

end**

the item_params

def item_params

```
    params.require(:prd_item).permit(:item_name, :brand, :item_no, :short_description, :long_description, :prd_type_id, :usr_vendor_property_id, :price,:base_price, :price_discount, :percentage_discount, :stock_count, :availability, :tags, :remove_image, :delivery_type , :min_stock_count,

                                 prd_item_images_attributes: [:id, :image, :description, :link, :_destroy ],

                                 prd_temp_variation_stores_attributes: [:id, :product_variations, :variation_items, :_destroy],
                                 prd_temp_compound_stores_attributes:[:id,:compound, :compound_item, :_destroy],
                                 prd_temp_spec_stores_attributes:[:id,:compound, :compound_item, :_destroy],
                                 prd_allisland_flat_deliveries_attributes: [:id,:delivery_period,:delivery_rate],
                                 prd_province_vise_deliveries_attributes: [:id , :province_name , :delivery_rate, :delivery_period]

                                 )
```

end

the rails consoler gets the Unpermitted parameters: prd_allisland_flat_deliveries

can anyone explain why

[image: view]

[image]

[image]

in case the pictures are not clear

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZqJOX4nMmWyVG2CxJznKKxLLsUkG+4ndBFdvxfx2TPouiQkIbYfvQ00moCdqFZWPd0nJ4ipCVY9JhVToESDCoQ==", "prd_item"=>{"item_name"=>"abc", "item_no"=>"666333", "brand"=>""
, "prd_type_id"=>"", "short_description"=>"", "long_description"=>"", "tags"=>"", "prd_item_images_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "description"=>"", "link"=>""}}, "base_price"=>"655", "price"=>"688
", "price_discount"=>"5", "prd_temp_spec_stores_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"spec_item"=>"", "spec"=>""}}, "prd_temp_variation_stores_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"product_variations"=>"", "variation_items"=>""}}, "prd_temp_
compound_stores_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"compound_item"=>"", "compound"=>""}}, "stock_count"=>"55", "min_stock_count"=>"5", "availability"=>"available", "delivery_type"=>"1", "prd_allisland_flat_deliveries"=>{"d
elivery_period"=>"255", "delivery_rate"=>"22"}, "prd_province_vise_deliveries"=>{"delivery_rate"=>"", "delivery_period"=>""}}, "commit"=>"ADD PRODUCT"}

Unpermitted parameters: prd_allisland_flat_deliveries, prd_province_vise_deliveries

SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "prd_allisland_flat_deliveries" ("prd_item_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["prd_item_id", 52], ["created_at", 2017-11-12 14:02:09 UTC], ["upd
ated_at", 2017-11-12 14:02:09 UTC]]

Comment: can you show the full form as it appears on the browser

Comment: see the new edition of the question

Comment: sorry I meant the view source of the form

Comment: you mean the code fragment

Comment: yes. I want to see what the code for the form has

Comment: the main form code is bulky to post here

Comment: @pasM Instead of posting the form screenshot, please post the console screen image which has error and parameters that have received on submitting the form.

Comment: @SathishkumarJayaraj  please see the new edition of my problem

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you do:

```
permit(
  ..., 
  :prd_allisland_flat_deliveries_attributes,
  :prd_province_vise_deliveries_attributes
)
```

But, you don't permit `:prd_allisland_flat_deliveries` or `:prd_province_vise_deliveries`. And that's what you have in your params.

So, you get the Unpermitted parameters errors. Either permit those parameters, or modify your partial to include `_attributes`.

To permit them:

```
params.require(:prd_item).permit(
  :item_name, 
  :brand, 
  :item_no, 
  :short_description, 
  :long_description, 
  :prd_type_id, 
  :usr_vendor_property_id, 
  :price,:base_price, 
  :price_discount, 
  :percentage_discount, 
  :stock_count, 
  :availability, 
  :tags, 
  :remove_image, 
  :delivery_type , 
  :min_stock_count,
  prd_item_images_attributes: [:id, :image, :description, :link, :_destroy ],
  prd_temp_variation_stores_attributes: [:id, :product_variations, :variation_items, :_destroy],
  prd_temp_compound_stores_attributes:[:id,:compound, :compound_item, :_destroy],
  prd_temp_spec_stores_attributes:[:id,:compound, :compound_item, :_destroy],
  prd_allisland_flat_deliveries: [:id,:delivery_period,:delivery_rate],
  prd_province_vise_deliveries: [:id , :province_name , :delivery_rate, :delivery_period]
)
```

Comment: how can i permit those params

Comment: Include them in your list of permitted parameters.

Comment: i'm little bit confused can you show how to do if you prefer

Comment: It's a very basic concept. Please read up on `require` and `permit`. I updated answer. Just remove `_attributes` from `prd_allisland_flat_deliveries_attributes` and `prd_province_vise_deliveries_attributes`.

Comment: after the changes it  gives me ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (PrdAllislandFlatDelivery(#132772536) expected, got Array(#20018484)):
error

Comment: Yeah, your code is a mess and has multiple problem areas. I don't know where you are in the world, but I could do a chat tomorrow (possibly).

Comment: can you give me a rough idea where i should correct

Comment: can we have adiscussion i'm struggling with this